Error while retrieving OAuth 2.0 Access Token in Azure AD integrated Spring Boot App
I have configured Azure AD credentials in my Spring Boot project's application.propertiesfile using the dependency spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory. Here is the configuration:
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=${TENANT_ID_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=${CLIENT_ID_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=${CLIENT_SECRET_ENV_VAR}

Application Code:
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String getUserInfo(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {

        // Retrieve the email or username from the principal
        String userName = principal.getAttribute("preferred_username");

        // Return a response with the user's email
        return "Hello: " + userName;
    }
}

Currently, I am encountering an error on a particular Azure Web App (ASP) server: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://login.microsoftonline.com/0d993ad3-fa73-421a-b129-1fe5590103f3/oauth2/v2.0/token": login.microsoftonline.com: Temporary failure in name resolution.
I have cross-checked the AD credentials and I am getting a successful response in the local environment and a different web app as well. After referring to some Google documents and links mentioned below, I have made the necessary adjustments, but I am still getting the same error on that web app.
Spring Boot Version:
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.5.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1600366/receiving-(invalid-token-response)-error-while-imp
Could u please guide me how to fix/resolve this issue and and what are the posssible reasons for this issue.
Here is the error screenshot for your reference.


can you share the scope you are using?

Currently we are not mentioned any scope in app.properties file is it required? And sometimes we mention redirect uri.

is the above the only configuration you are using in the application.properties?

Can you provide more details of code?

Application.properties:
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=${TENANT_ID_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=${CLIENT_ID_ENV_VAR}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=${CLIENT_SECRET_ENV_VAR}

Application Code:
package com.function;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

   @GetMapping("user")
   public String AccessManagementEntity(
           @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal,
           @RequestParam(name = "path", required = false) String path) {
           String email = principal.getAttribute("preferred_username");
           return "User Id:"+ email;

       }
}



17
5.5.0



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


com.azure.spring
spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory

Can you add the code in the question not in comments? check the secret and ID's are correct or not?

Sorry Kamali, Updated Question now, I ahve already checked Client Secret and this Application is perfectly working locally issue is triggering while hosting in azure webapp. i have enabled Sesssion Affinity to ensure sticky sessions on webapp but still triggering this issue.

Have you added the Web app URL in the service principle under Authentication?

I successfully retrieved the username and access token both locally and in the Azure Web App.
HelloController.java :
I have modified the HelloController as below to retrieve the Access Token.
            @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,
            @RequestParam(name = "path", required = false) String path) {
        if (principal != null) {
            String userName = principal.getAttribute("preferred_username");
            String accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            return "Hello: " + userName + "<br>Access Token: " + accessToken;
        } else {
            return "No user found";
        }
    }
}

Below is the complete HelloController class.
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.annotation.RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String AccessManagementEntity(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal,
            @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,
            @RequestParam(name = "path", required = false) String path) {
        if (principal != null) {
            String userName = principal.getAttribute("preferred_username");
            String accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            return "Hello: " + userName + "<br>Access Token: " + accessToken;
        } else {
            return "No user found";
        }
    }
}

SecurityConfig.java :
I added the signin logic in the  SecurityConfig class.
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("/signin/**", "/login/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .authenticationSuccessHandler((webFilterExchange, authentication) -> {
                            return webFilterExchange.getExchange().getResponse().setComplete();
                        })
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}

application.properties :
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=<clientID>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=<clientSecret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-authentication-method=client_secret_basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.scope=openid,profile,email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-name=Azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/v2.0
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.authorization-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.token-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.user-info-uri=https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=<tenantID>
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I have added the redirect URI for both local and Azure Web Apps in the service principal under Authentication, as shown below.
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure

<AzureWebAppsURL>/login/oauth2/code/azure


Local Output :

I successfully retrieved the userName and Access Token in the browser.

Note : Before deploying, make sure to update the redirect URI in the application.properties file to the web app URL as shown below.
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri=<AzureWebAppsURL>/login/oauth2/code/azure

Azure Web App Output :
I successfully retrieved the userName and Access Token in the Azure Web apps.


Thanks for your assistance, Kamali.

To resolve the [invalid_token_response] error in Azure Web App, change the DNS zone option in the networking section from 'Custom' to 'Default' (Azure provided).
